# Concatenate multiindex daframe with series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multiindex dataframe that contains the features for training a machine learning model.

```
X_train

win      -1           0           1
res       A     B     A     B     A     B
id  pos   
foo 0     0.1   0.2   0.3   0.1   0.5   0.6
    1     0.3   0.7   0.2   0.1   0.4   0.6
    2     0.1   0.2   0.3   0.1   0.5   0.6
bar 0     0.1   0.0   0.3   0.1   0.5   0.6
    1     0.1   0.2   0.0   0.3   0.9   0.6
    2     0.1   0.2   0.3   0.1   0.5   0.6
```

And a pandas series (or dataframe) with the class labels

```
y_train
    
id  pos   
foo 0     0
    1     2
    2     1
bar 0     0
    1     0
    2     1
Name: Class
```

I want to concatenate them and obtain

```
full_train

win      -1           0           1          Class
res       A     B     A     B     A     B    
id  pos   
foo 0     0.1   0.2   0.3   0.1   0.5   0.6  0  
    1     0.3   0.7   0.2   0.1   0.4   0.6  2
    2     0.1   0.2   0.3   0.1   0.5   0.6  1
bar 0     0.1   0.0   0.3   0.1   0.5   0.6  0
    1     0.1   0.2   0.0   0.3   0.9   0.6  0
    2     0.1   0.2   0.3   0.1   0.5   0.6  1
```

But if I do `full_train = pd.concat([X_train, y_train], axis=1)`, I obtain:

```
          (-1,A)(-1,B)(0,A) (0,B)(1,A) (1,B) Class
id  pos   
foo 0     0.1   0.2   0.3   0.1   0.5   0.6  0  
    1     0.3   0.7   0.2   0.1   0.4   0.6  2
    2     0.1   0.2   0.3   0.1   0.5   0.6  1
bar 0     0.1   0.0   0.3   0.1   0.5   0.6  0
    1     0.1   0.2   0.0   0.3   0.9   0.6  0
    2     0.1   0.2   0.3   0.1   0.5   0.6  1
```

Is it possible to obtain my expected output? Does Pandas support this kind of mixed columns being both multiindex and singleindex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas does support this! However there's some roundabout under the hood knowledge you'll need to know for concatenation to get this to work as expected.

For the below examples I'll be using this dataframe and this series `y_train`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[-1, 0, 1], ["A", "B"]], names=["win", "res"])
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["foo", "bar"], [0, 1, 2]], names=["id", "pos"])

m = len(columns)
n = len(index)

data = np.random.randint(5, size=(m * n)).reshape(m, n)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)

print(df)
win     -1     0     1   
res      A  B  A  B  A  B
id  pos                  
foo 0    3  4  4  4  4  1
    1    4  1  4  3  1  0
    2    0  4  2  2  3  2
bar 0    3  2  1  4  1  1
    1    0  3  1  1  0  3
    2    2  0  2  1  0  1
```

Labels:

```
y_train = pd.Series(np.random.randint(3, size=m), index=index, name="class")

print(y_train)
id   pos
foo  0      2
     1      1
     2      2
bar  0      1
     1      1
     2      2
Name: class, dtype: int32
```

If your `y_train` is a Series, you don't need to use `concat` at all. The most straightforward method is to simply assign your `y_train` series into the original dataframe.

```
new_df = df.copy() # preserving original dataframe for use in later examples
new_df["class"] = y_train

print(new_df)
win     -1     0     1    class
res      A  B  A  B  A  B      
id  pos                        
foo 0    3  4  4  4  4  1     2
    1    4  1  4  3  1  0     1
    2    0  4  2  2  3  2     2
bar 0    3  2  1  4  1  1     1
    1    0  3  1  1  0  3     1
    2    2  0  2  1  0  1     2

# We can select our "class" column and get its `Series` out via:
print(new_df["class"])

id   pos
foo  0      2
     1      1
     2      2
bar  0      1
     1      1
     2      2
Name: class, dtype: int32

# Then to access our other columns, we'll need to supply a key as a tuple:
print(new_df[(-1, "A")])

id   pos
foo  0      4
     1      1
     2      4
bar  0      2
     1      3
     2      0
Name: (-1, B), dtype: int32
```

Now things get a little trickier if your `y_train` is a dataframe instead of a Series. However this approach also solves your `concat` question as well. All you need to do is replace your label dataframe's (`y_train`) column index with a `MultiIndex` that has the same number of levels with the other dataframe you're attempting to concatenate with. You'll need to use empty levels to achieve this (an empty level is a level whose only value is an empty string. NOT None or NaN)

```
new_ytrain = y_train.to_frame() # promote y_train to a dataframe

# In order to feed this into concat, we'll need to give our dataframe a columnar multiindex
# This multiindex essentially has an empty second level
new_ytrain.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([new_ytrain.columns, [""]])

print(new_ytrain)
        class
             
id  pos      
foo 0       2
    1       1
    2       2
bar 0       1
    1       1
    2       2
```

In the representation of our `y_train` dataframe, you'll see a space between our column titles and the actual data. This represents the empty levels we've inserted. Now that both our original dataframe and our `y_train` have a columnar `MultiIndex` with 2 levels, we can use concat as expected with no issues:

```
out = pd.concat([df, new_ytrain], axis=1)

print(out)
win     -1     0     1    class
res      A  B  A  B  A  B      
id  pos                        
foo 0    3  4  4  4  4  1     2
    1    4  1  4  3  1  0     1
    2    0  4  2  2  3  2     2
bar 0    3  2  1  4  1  1     1
    1    0  3  1  1  0  3     1
    2    2  0  2  1  0  1     2
```

Like with the assignment approach, we can select our "class" column in this dataframe easily.

```
print(out["class"])

id   pos
foo  0      2
     1      1
     2      2
bar  0      1
     1      1
     2      2
Name: class, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Thank you. I already got something like your approach, but I got confused when with `new_df.columns.levels` I got `FrozenList([[-1, 0, 1, 'Class'], ['A', 'B', '']])`, which displays the df correctly but seems like a conceptual mistake assigning `Class` to the same level group as `-1, 0, 1`

Comment: Using the `concat` approach you can assign `"class"` to the same level as `"A", "B"` and assign an empty level to `-1, 0, 1`. You would just have to select the class column via `new_df[("", "class")]`. Though I'm not sure if that would feel like more or less of a conceptual mistake given your data.

Comment: Actually the class should be level free by design. Basically every `foo` or `bar` gets assigned a class. The number of level of the features don't influence the class.

Comment: That makes sense, though the only two options I can think of are to either stick it in the row index as its own level (e.g. having `"id", "pos", "class"` in your index). Or just keep it as a separate `Series` (potentially sticking the dataframe and the labels in a named tuple to keep them together, but still separate?). Unfortunately, I don't think there's any way to have it be a column in the dataframe while also keeping it apart from the `MultiIndex` columns that you already have set up.

Comment: That's what I imagined, though it really bugs me not to have such a feature in pandas. Of course, when using scikit-learn it doesn't really matter much since everything gets converted to `np.array`, but I really like to keep my dataframes organized. Thanks again for the clarification.